# How to access data from orientdb on a PHP Page?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, orientdb

I have installed OrientDb PHP Official driver from https://github.com/orientechnologies/PhpOrient.

Now, In the PHP Page, I just want it to display only values of attributes of 'user' collection such as user_id, username, email_id,mobile etcusing the print_r() function.

```
 $client = new PhpOrient( 'localhost', 2424);
 $client->username = 'root';
```

The code which displays the output are as follows ::

```
$client->password = 'root';
$client->connect(); 
$ClusterMap = $client->dbOpen( 'krshop', 'root', 'root' ); 
$data = $client->query( 'select from user limit 10' ); 
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
```

[User collection data using php of orientdb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyEAm.png)

Comment: The code which displays the output are as follows ::                          $client = new PhpOrient( 'localhost', 2424);
$client->username = 'root';                                                                $client->password = 'root';
$client->connect();
$ClusterMap = $client->dbOpen( 'krshop', 'root', 'root' );
$data = $client->query( 'select from user limit 10' );
echo "<pre>";print_r($data);

Answer (score 5):

try this code:

```
$client = new OrientDB('localhost', 2424);
$client->connect('root', 'root');
$client->DBOpen('krshop', 'root', 'root');
$data = $client->select('select from user limit 10');
```